# Waiting for a thread to finish in python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, tkinter

The main thread in my program creates the UI. `thread1` communicates with the server and `thread2` writes the results to an Excel sheet. I want `thread2` to start only after `thread1` has finished executing. However, when I use `thread1.join()`, the UI goes irresponsive.  How do I fix this? (Both `thread1` and `thread2` are created in the main thread.)

Comment: Tkinter is **not** thread safe

Comment: din't get that advice early on :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `thread1.join()` from within `thread2`'s `run` method, so that's it's `thread2` that waits on `thread1`, instead of the main thread.